# state design pattern - when a new state add to parent state, this cause another state also change, what do we do to prevent change another state

Tags: oop, design-patterns, state-pattern

In state design pattern ,In the worst case when a new state is added to parent State, it causes all other states to change as well.
 What changes need to be made to the design to prevent successive changes?

Comment: it's one of the reasons we use state pattern to make sure we don't miss on such type of things. once a state is added it must be accounted for and the machine must be predictable with the new configuration.

Comment: Had you used conditionals to explicitly check things etc. it's easier to miss things. Especially when things are in multiple places